# Forced importing syntax due to duplicate react versions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I import React modules using auto-import feature (you write say `useState` in component body and it automatically gets imported for me), i use vitejs as a build tool.

Expected results:

```
import {useState} from "react"
```

Actual results:

```
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.production.min"
```

### Update: April 3

after testing with `create-react-app`, the issue is resolved ( it uses `react v18.0.0`). Vite uses `react v17.0.2`

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Do you have only one suggestion when you use auto import ?

Comment: It is being imported from a minified react file. He wants that once he use VS Code shortcut for importing, it should import from "react" not minified one.

Comment: Auto-imported _by what_, though? If this is IDE behaviour, for example, it might be helpful to know _which one_.

Comment: sorry for late response, i use native vs-code intellisense for auto-completion, i cannot trace the cause of this problem, however it may be due to different react versions used in the same project (not sure yet)